# Tokenizing a string C

Tags: c

Hello I am having trouble with a function that receives a string from a client in the format "number op number" ,op being a (+,-.*,/), then returns an answer to the client.  I need help splitting the string into two num variables and one op variable.

Here is the function in question.

```
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n, i, size, j;
    while (1) {
        bzero(buff, MAX);
        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

        long int num1, num2, op;
        char temp[256];
        strcpy(temp, buff);
        sscanf(buff, "%s %s %s", num1, op, num2);

        // print buffer which contains the client contents
        printf("From client: %ld | | %ld", num1, num2);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: `sscanf(buff, "%s %s %s", num1, op, num2);`
  should be       
 `sscanf(buff, "%ld %ld %ld", &num1, &op, &num2);`

maybe consider changing op to *char*

Answer (score 4):

The correct format for reading a `long int` is `%ld`, `%s` is for strings.

You need `&` before any variables being read into with `scanf()` except for strings (since arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments).

`op` should be `char` rather than `long int`, and you should use `%c` format to read it.

You should limit the size of `read()` to `sizeof buff - 1` so there will always be a null byte after the message that was read.

There's no need for the `temp` variable, you can just scan from `buff`.

You need to check the return value of `read()` to tell if the connection has been closed.

```
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n, i, size, j;
    while (1) {
        bzero(buff, MAX);
        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
        int n = read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if (n == 0) { // EOF
            break;
        } else if (n < 0) {
            perror("read");
            break;
        }

        long int num1, num2;
        char op;
        sscanf(temp, "%ld %c %ld", &num1, &op, &num2);

        // print buffer which contains the client contents
        printf("From client: %ld | %c | %ld\n", num1, op, num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solution is working except that the expression does not get printed out until the connection is broken, and when it does it's in an infinite loop.

Comment: Add `\n` to the printf, output is line-buffered.

Comment: You don't check for errors or EOF from `read()`.